How to compute the Poisson integral using a parameter-dependent integral

using the integral formula

$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1-r^2}{1-2 r \cos \theta+r^2} \mathrm{~d} \theta=1,(0<r<1),
$$
Quesion:get the value of the following formula when $(r>0, r \neq 1)$
$$
I(r)=\int_0^{2 \pi} \ln \left(1-2 r \cos \theta+r^2\right) \mathrm{d} \theta
$$
I can compute it by complex integral,but I dont konw how to calculate by   parameter-depence integral,here is my try:
First, let's consider the given equation:
$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2} d\theta = 1, (0<r<1)$
We can rewrite this as:
$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2} d\theta = 2\pi, (0<r<1)$
Now, let's differentiate both sides with respect to r:
$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}\right) d\theta = 0$
Using the quotient rule, we get:
$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{-2r(1-2r\cos\theta+r^2) - (1-r^2)(2r-2\cos\theta)}{(1-2r\cos\theta+r^2)^2} d\theta = 0$
Simplifying:
$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{-2r+2r\cos\theta}{(1-2r\cos\theta+r^2)^2} d\theta = 0$
then what I should do?
